# How to solve this This sample requires a Mysql database. Please edit the configuration file: application.config.php?

Tags: php, hybridauth

i am using hybridauth to get userinformation from social web sites like facebook,twitter, etc.[PHP lib to connect](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/)
i configured using install.php which is available in lib itself.

when i tried to use some examples available i get the following errore `This sample requires a Mysql database. Please edit the configuration file: application.config.php`

i really don't know where this file `application.config.php` is available.

also i get `got an error! Hybridauth Library needs the CURL PHP extension.`

since i am very new to PHP blinking what to do next.

Please help me to solve this.

Regards
Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need php-curl.. most repo's php installs include this, so it's odd you haven't gotton it. You have specified what OS you're working on, but a quick google search will give you instructions on installing this. If you're working on a RHEL-based system, do;

```
yum install php-common
yum install php-curl
```

The former installing all php common packs, and the latter specifically installing curl.

likewise, you'll need to find where application.config.php is - again, on RHEL-based systems, you can run;

```
find -name application.config.php
```

- otherwise, find out how to do a system search on the OS you're currently working on. Looks like it's just a standard issue where you haven't defined your mysql information (database name, username, password); once you input these into your application.config.php, you should be good to go.

Best of luck with it.

- Eoghan

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am using windows 7 enterprise

Comment: In that case, just use windows search function ;) you can edit your php.ini to include the curl extension.

Comment: it helped, thanks man :), just un commented in the file $XAMMP_PATH$\php\php.ini, extension=php_curl.dll this line